# android : fromhtml is leaving font details in the string

Tags: android, html, fonts

I am converting html string using `Html.fromHtml(sBody)` to add it to an edittext . I need editext , so I cant use webview to loaddata .

```
et.setText(Html.fromHtml(sBody));
```

What I see is the converted text has some font detail added in the beginning .
sample data is  :

```
!-- /* Font Definitions */ @font-face   {font-family:"Cambria Math";    panose-1:2 4 5 3 5 4 6 3 2 4;} @font-face   {font-family:Calibri;   panose-1:2 15 5 2 2 2 4 3 2 4;} @font-face
```

how can I remove this .

please help

Comment: I do not think that android supports that kind of syntax

Comment: What is the desired output?

Comment: i am trying to put email body in edittext . so the string is email html text .

Comment: when i do webview.loadData(sBody, "text/html", "utf-8"); it works perfect , but i need to show it in editext

Comment: Didn't get, What you want to say...?

Answer (score 2):

> how can i remove this

Remove it yourself from the HTML before passing it to `Html.fromHtml()`.

`Html.fromHtml()` does not handle all possible HTML, nor is it meant to. It only deals with the subset of HTML tags that are relevant for `TextView` and its subclasses. Other stuff -- in this case, some inline CSS -- it is going to largely ignore, which may leave it as visible text.

So, find yourself an HTML parser and strip out unnecessary cruft.

Comment: i had to remove <style> tag .